# Close previous slot if still running

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I got a searchfield that triggers a database search.

`connect(searchField,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(searchSong(QString)));`

But the database search takes longer then typing the next search condition.

SLOTS are queued but I don't want this. When a new signal is send the previous SLOT needs to be cancelled and restarted.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are going the wrong way. What you have to do is create a flag that indicates if there is a pending request, and if there is when searchSong is called then cancel it and launch a new request:

***.h**

```
private:
    bool is_busy;
```

***.cpp**

```
// constructor
FooClass::FooClass(foo_paramenters):
   BaseClass(args), is_busy(false)
{
    // some code
    connect(searchField, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &FooClass::searchSong);
}

void FooClass::searchSong(const QString & text){
    if(is_busy)
        cancel_request();
    is_busy = true;
    send_request(text);
}

void FooClass::receive_answer_from_request(){
    // some code
    is_busy = false;
}
```